# Timezone is not changing in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.8

I want to change timezone but it is not working

```
I have changed timezone in config/app.php

My previous timezone was 

'timezone' => 'Asia/Kolkata',

and i changed it to 

'timezone' => 'UTC',
```

But it is not working, please help me.

Comment: try `php artisan config:clear`

Comment: after changing run `php artisan optimize:clear`

Comment: @KamleshPaul i have run this command but still not working

Comment: @tajamulhussain how you are checking .? it is not working

Comment: @KamleshPaul I am checking through  dd(date_default_timezone_get());

Comment: then something wrong with your code mine it is working you should debug your code

Comment: @ I don't know why it is not changing?

Comment: @Hamelraj I have run this command still same result.